# Make a Linux install CD on a Mac but Use it to Install Linux on a Windows Machine

Tags: installation, windows, mac

I've tried a couple of times to install Linux on my Windows machine using a CD created with Mac OS X... Have not been sucessful. Any idea why? Perhaps I'm downloading the wrong version of Linux?s

Comment: Define 'have not been successful'. Errors? How was the CD created?

Comment: I guess you extracted the iso and then burned it? You shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

First, download Ubuntu either [32bit or 64bit](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), according to the CPU that you have  onto your MAC.  Then see [How to burn a DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx), or [How to create a bootable USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) using OS X.  and follow the [Guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest) here.